# How to edit the network adapter changes from the command line?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, gateway, cinnamon

I have plugged a Screen Monitor (HDMI), keyboard and mouse in my Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1 machine and had set up a fixed IP address using the Graphics Interface as in the picture below: (I had taken a picture on the time I did it, and saved for later reference)

[image]

Now, I unplugged the Screen Monitor (HDMI), keyboard and mouse from my Linux machine and disabled the user interface with `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`, and adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` on my `/etc/default/grub` file.

With this my machine uses as little as 80MB of RAM from the boot when I connect to it by SSH from the local network. However, I need to change the default gateway I had set `10.254.254.254` because my router changed.

How can I change the default gateway without having to plug back a Screen Monitor (HDMI), keyboard, mouse and re-enabling the user interface I disabled on `/etc/default/grub`?

I accessed my file `/etc/network/interfaces` from SSH and it is empty:

```
  1 # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
  2 auto lo
  3 iface lo inet loopback
```

Where did the Cinnamon Network Manager (First Picture) put my default gateway `10.254.254.254` when I applied the changes?

Comment: Run `sudo grep -rl 10.254.254.254 /etc`. The file holding your config will probably be there (possibly among others).

Comment: Thanks!!!! I found it on `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1`

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `sudo grep -rl 10.254.254.254 /etc`

I found it on `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1`